# How to intersect multiple lists if one of them is going to be empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have some lists made using some conditions in c#.. Thus if any condition is false that list remains empty.. but I still need to intersect it with the other lists to get the final output.. any suggestions how to do it ?

Comment: "...some lists  using some conditions..." Can you be more specific what you have, what you want, what you've tried and what didn't work? Currently it's not clear at all.

Comment: Please provide some code samples, which you have tried. It will help the fellow users to understand the question more clear.

Comment: You need to intersect an empty list with a non-empty? Result will ALLWAYS be empty, you know?

Comment: Can you provide example data? Please show inputs and outputs required.

Answer (score 4):

As simple static method:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Intersect<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] lists)
{
    return lists.Where(l => l.Any()).Aggregate((l1, l2) => l1.Intersect(l2));
}
```

You can use it like

```
var list1 = new List<string>() { "abc", "cde" };
var list2 = new List<string>() { "abc", "xyz" };
var list3 = new List<string>();

var arrayOfLists = new List<string>[] {list1, list2, list3};

var paramList= Intersect(list1, list2, list3);
var arrayList = Intersect(listOfLists);
```

Be careful to pass an array instead of list, otherwise T is List which returns the original list.

Comment: You're welcome. I would appreciate to mark this as answer, if it was the right solution.

Comment: This should be added to the .NET Framework by default.

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allows you to do this even if one `IEnumerable<T>` is empty.

However, as soon as there is at least one empty list, the intersect result will always be empty - is this what you need?

Comment: I think the list can be empty in some conditions, not always

Comment: That's my understanding as well. I edited my answer to clarify which scope of "always" I mean. ;)

Answer (score 1):

So, after you have all your lists, put them into an array, then you can do as bellow sample (suppose you have all lists of strings)

```
        var list1 = new List<string>();
        var list2 = new List<string>();
        var list3 = new List<string>();

        var allLists = new List<string>[] { list1, list2, list3 };
        // need to be sure you have >= 1 list(s)
        var result = allLists[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < allLists.Length; i++)
        {
            result = result.Intersect(allLists[i]).ToList();
        }

        // ok, you get the result
```

Comment: I intersected the list itself as told by Matt!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could use the `Count` property

```
List<Object> your_list = new List<Object>();
if(your_list.Count!=0){
// do your stuff
}
else{
//skip
}
```